# how to get a character from user without stopping the the execution in C language?

Tags: c

`getch` or `getche` stops the output until a character is not entered. I want my code to keep asking for character in a loop and not wants to stop the execution of code?

Comment: Look into either `select` or threads

Comment: It is operating system specific

Comment: Look into `kbhit()`.

Comment: @CoolGuy: That's not a standard function.

Comment: @Olaf I know. But neither is `getch`/`getche` which seems to work for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a **non-blocking** input call (that means it does not block but return immediately if no input is available).

If you are talking about `getch()`, the [curses function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch), it's easy to make it non-blocking: just call [`timeout(0)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/timeout).

Just for fun, I created a "snake" using `curses` functions stripped down to the bare minimum, [for reference](https://github.com/Zirias/minsnake/blob/master/minsnake.c)

Comment: I am making a snake game in which i want my code to ask for character i.e up, down, left, right in C language

Comment: So? You typically want non-blocking input for that. `getch()` is not a standard c function, I told you what to do **if** you mean the `curses` `getch()`, see also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000935/why-doesnt-getch-read-the-last-character-entered/44003182#44003182). If you're talking about another library's `getch()`, you need to be more specific in your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your computer freezing and waiting for input when your CLI C or C++ program attempts to read a key from the keyboard (say, by using "getchar") is not under direct control of your program. What's happening "under the hood" is this: your program makes a function call to whatever "terminal" program is handling your from-keyboard input and to-screen output. In Linux this is called "console". In raw Windows it's called "cmd.exe". In Cygwin it's called "mintty.exe". It's the *terminal* which causes the "freeze" by *failing* to return until a user presses one-or-more keys followed by the Enter key.

To fix this, you need to temporarily change the settings of your terminal. To do that, research the name of the program used to configure your terminal. In Linux and Cygwin, this is "stty". The stty command for changing "timeout" from "∞ deciseconds" (the default) to "1 decisecond" (which is what you need) is "time 1".

A function for getting a keystroke without delaying program execution on a Linux or Cygwin system looks like this (you'll have to change the contents of the system() calls if your system uses something other than stty to configure its terminal):

```
// Check for recent keypress on keyboard; if there is one,
// get that character; but time-out after 1 decisecond if
// input does not immediately occur (keep executing program):
char getkey_unlocked (void)
{
   char A;
   system("stty -icanon");
   system("stty -echo");
   system("stty time 1"); // CHANGE TIMEOUT FROM ∞ TO 1/10 SECOND
   A = (char)getchar();
   system("stty echo");
   system("stty icanon");
   return A;
}
```

That will return "-1" if no key has been pressed, or the ASCII code for any key which is pressed.

Answer (score -2):

You should use concurrent programming, with that you can do something like: while a father process waits the input, the child executes the rest of the code.

You can do that in linux by using the function `fork()`.

To check if the current process is father or child you should do:

```
// CREATE PID AND PROCESS
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

if (pid < 0)
  puts("ERROR");
else if (pid == 0)
  puts("CHILD");
  // CODE YOU WANT TO EXECUTE
else
  puts("FATHER");
  // CODE THAT WAITS FOR INPUT
```

You can use threads too.

Comment: How about a cloud-based application just to get a keypress? That would be even more complicated.

Comment: I am making a snake game in which i want my code to ask for character i.e up, down, left, right in C language